# How to fetch parameters from the application.properties file for a test case

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have the following Controller class

```
@Component
public class Controller{

@Value("${details}")
private String detail1;

@Value("${otherdetails}")
private String detail2;

public ModelClass getSomeDetails(String name, int age) {
   Serviceclass serviceobject = new Serviceclass();

   //some Code

   serviceobject.doSomething(name, age, detail1, detail2);
  }
}
```

Once this is done, I need to test this method in a test case. My test class is as below. I have the application.properties file in the /src/test/resources folder

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class testClass{
@Test
public void getDetails() {
Controller controllerObject = new Controller();
controllerObject.getSomeDetails("name", 22);

//Other code
  }
}
```

When I do this, the application.properties has the details and otherdetails parameter but it is returning null.

How should I use them to get the value in the Controller class?

Comment: `src\main\resources\application.properties` is the structure right??

Comment: Yes, I have the file in that location as well. since that did not work, I have over-ridden the properties file by creating a new file under the above mentioned location

Comment: @rjdkolb , `@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let Spring instantiate your `Controller` class and not manually do a `new` yourself:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class testClass{
  @Autowired
  private Controller controllerObject;

  @Test
  public void getDetails() {

    controllerObject.getSomeDetails("name", 22);

    //Other code
  }

  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public Controller controller() {
      return new Controller();
   }
  }
}
```

Note that you can also replace `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Instead of adding the inner class, you can also have Spring test start your complete application by annotating the test with `@SpringBootTest`. If you know what part of your application you want to test, you can get better performance by using [test slicing](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests).

Comment: Doing this was not successful either. I ended up with UnsatisfiedDependencyException where error creating bean with name "...controller.testClass"

Comment: The above is error free with adding `@SpringBootTest`, but I still get null for the values from the property files

Comment: @evan I suggest you create a sample application to further investigate the issue. You can also manually configure the values to use in the test with `@TestPropertySource(properties="details=x")`. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source

Answer (score 1):

Do not manually instantiate the controller, rather `AutoWire` the controller into your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class testClass{

@Autowired Controller controllerObject;

@Test
public void getDetails() {
controllerObject.getSomeDetails("name", 22);

//Other code
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this was not successful either. I ended up with UnsatisfiedDependencyException where error creating bean with name "...controller.testClass"